# how to store csv file in array?

Tags: bash, shell

i have a csv file like this

accept_language browser browser_height browser_width campaign c_color channel click_action click_action_type click_context click_context_type click_sourceid click_tag code_ver color connection_type cookies country ct_connect_type currency curr_factor curr_rate cust_hit_time_gmt cust_visid daily_visitor date_time

i want to store each value in single array like
Array1=( "accept_lanugage" "browser" "browser_height" and so on )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easier than you think with `space` separated values in the file:

```
array=( $(<filename.csv) )
```

Which will use the default internal field separator to break the words on a space and load each word as an element in the array.